# how to align text input in Angular-Material tool bar?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular-material

I'm having a problem when trying to align input elements with buttons on an angular material toolbar.

Here is a code pen: http://codepen.io/curtwagner1984/pen/amgdXj

Here is my html:

```
<md-toolbar class="md-hue-1" layout-align="start center" style="min-height:15px; height: 50px" ng-show="$ctrl.showSearch">
    <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
        <md-button ng-click="$ctrl.showSearch = !$ctrl.showSearch">
            back
        </md-button>
        <md-input-container flex="">
            <input ng-model="searchInput" placeholder="Search here">
        </md-input-container>
        <md-input-container>
            <md-select ng-model="$ctrl.test">
                <md-option value="Option 1 Not Align">Option 1</md-option>
                <md-option value="Option 2 Not Align">Option 2</md-option>
            </md-select>
        </md-input-container>

        <md-button ng-click="$ctrl.showSearch = !$ctrl.showSearch">
            Search
        </md-button>
        <md-button ng-click="showListBottomSheet($event)">
            settings
        </md-button>
    </div>

</md-toolbar>
```

The CSS is the default Angular Material CSS file. 
Would be glad if someone could point me to how to achieve alignment here.

I also looked into this: http://blog.sodhanalibrary.com/2015/07/header-design-with-angularjs-material-ui.html#.WBS-Y-B96Uk But didn't find a good solution, when I try their code, my input container in the toolbar is still not aligned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way of doing it - [CodePen](http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/PGrNQp)

The things to note are:

- Remove `class="md-toolbar-tools"`
- Put `md-select` within an `md-container`
- Enclose the two `md-input-container` within a `div`

This uses the Angular Material way of doing things and doesn't need extra CSS.

Edit 1: If you want the height of the `md-toolbar` to be 50px you can easily set its style be so **but** the input label will go off the screen.

Edit 2: If you want the 50px height without the label going off the screen you can add the `md-no-float` attribute to the `md-input-container`.

Markup

```
<div ng-controller="DemoCtrl as ctrl" layout="column" ng-cloak="" class="autocompletedemoBasicUsage" ng-app="MyApp">

  <md-toolbar class="md-hue-1" ng-show="true">
    <div layout="row" layout-align="start center">
      <md-button ng-click="$ctrl.showSearch = !$ctrl.showSearch">
        back
      </md-button>
      <div layout="row" flex>
        <md-input-container flex>
          <input ng-model="searchInput" placeholder="Search here">
        </md-input-container>
        <md-input-container flex>
          <md-select ng-model="$ctrl.test">
            <md-option value="Option 1 Not Align">Option 1</md-option>
            <md-option value="Option 2 Not Align">Option 2</md-option>
          </md-select>
        </md-input-container>
      </div>
      <md-button ng-click="$ctrl.showSearch = !$ctrl.showSearch">
        Search
      </md-button>
      <md-button ng-click="showListBottomSheet($event)">
        settings
      </md-button>
    </div>

  </md-toolbar>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work if you add `style="min-height:15px; height: 50px">` to `<md-toolbar>`. I want the height of the toolbar to be smaller than it's default height value.

Comment: @Curtwagner1984 Fair enough, the only problem doing that will be the input label going off screen, which happens in your example and using the CSS in the other answer. You can easily do that with my example by setting the height of `md-toolbar` to 50px.

Comment: Indeed. Is there a way to align the text && make the toolbar height lower without that happening ?

Comment: @Curtwagner1984 You could add this CSS - md-toolbar md-input-container {margin-bottom: -22px} **but** the alignment with the buttons isn't great.

Comment: @Curtwagner1984 The other option is to use the solution with my answer edit or the other answer and add the attribute `md-no-float` to the `md-input-container` of the input.

Comment: `md-no-float` Helps with the label, but with your solution, the text input and the buttons are still misaligned. It's strange, though... I've added `md-toolbar md-input-container {margin-bottom: -0px}` and now it's perfectly aligned http://codepen.io/curtwagner1984/pen/EgBymP

Comment: @Curtwagner1984 Glad you've got a nice solution. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Add this class for all your elements that you want to align.

```
.align-items {
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```